# The HTML Form and the corresponding xmlhttprequest script doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to set up a simple HTML form, and want the response to be added to the HTML form with `xmlhttprequest`.

Im new in scripting and does not fully understand the handling of objects

The HTML form:

```
    <form id="frm1" action="./cgi-bin/input.cgi">
      WPT: <input type="text" name="wpt1"><br>
      Time: <input type="text" name="time1"><br><br>
      <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <p id="demo">RESULT HERE</p>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "./cgi-bin/input.cgi", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

The cgi code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import cgi, cgitb 
    cgitb.enable() 
    data = cgi.FieldStorage()
    print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
    print("Data: ")
    print(data["wpt1"].value)
    print(data["time1"].value)
```

I expect that the string "Data: [wpt1] [time1]" to be located at RESULT HERE, where [wpt1] and [time1] has the values from input data.

The error message is:

```
=>   12 print(data["wpt1"].value)

data = FieldStorage(None, None, []), ].value = []
```

My understanding of the error message is that no data is submitted.

When using this code for the script part the input is submitted and printed, but not as a content of the HTML Form.

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you either use POST or send values as query params. method 1:

```
<form id="frm1" action="./cgi-bin/input.cgi">
      WPT: <input type="text" id="wpt1" name="wpt1"><br>
      Time: <input type="text" id="time1" name="time1"><br><br>
      <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <p id="demo">RESULT HERE</p>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "./cgi-bin/input.cgi?wpt1="+document.getElementById("wpt1").value+"&time1="+document.getElementById("time1").value, true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

or method 2:

```
<form id="frm1" action="./cgi-bin/input.cgi">
      WPT: <input type="text" id="wpt1" name="wpt1"><br>
      Time: <input type="text" id="time1" name="time1"><br><br>
      <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <p id="demo">RESULT HERE</p>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "./cgi-bin/input.cgi", true);
      xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({"wpt1":document.getElementById("wpt1").value,"time1":document.getElementById("time1").value}));
    }
    </script>
```